# Update 3 columns if other columns are not empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

So i have 6 columns and i set values.What i want is if the 1-2-3 columns that are not empty, i want to set those values to 4-5-6 cells else if the 1-2-3 columns are empty or null to write them there.

```
update STORETRADELINES 
set SP_ORDERSTATUS = 6, 
WHERE SP_WAREHOUSEDATE is null and SP_REFQTY is null
```

I get syntax error on where.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by *empty* you mean *null*, that would be:

```
update mytable
set col1 = 4, col2 = 5, col3 = 6
where col1 is null and col2 is null and col3 is null
```

Note: database tables do not have *cells*, they have *columns*. Using the proper terminology makes it easier for others to understand what you mean.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: @MixMasteR: you probably are not running the query exactly as provided. The query I gave you would not generate this error: [example on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4ec8f37bcc2548f82482bfbcd763d18c).

Comment: script is fine but i want to set col4,col5,col6 some values if col1,2,3 is not null else if 1,2,3 are null i want values go there.